# Using 2 Bean in One Page

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, xhtml

I have a primeface tree in a page. I made it composite component. Basically it sets **selectedNodeName** property of TreeBean. Im planing to use this tree component in different pages. Im trying to use this composite component in a page when composite component(which is a primeface tree) selectednode changed h:outputText will be updated. The problem here is composite compenent is managed by one bean and rest of the page is managed by another bean. Components selectedNodeName property is in *TreeBean* and i want to use this property in *SomeBean* so i can update h:outputText value from *SomeBean*. Basically i want to get **selectedNodeName** from *TreeBean* and use it in *SomeBean*.

```
<div id="somediv" >
    <h:outputText id="thisis" value="#{someBean.selectedNodeName}"/>
</div>


<cc:someComponent updateButton=":mainForm:treeComponent:someTree :mainForm:thisis"
id="treeComponent" updateAjax=":mainForm:thisis" />
```

I tried managed property, but no success. selectedNodeName property is always null never sets to treeBean's property selectedNodeName.

```
    @ManagedProperty(value="#{treeBean.selectedNodeName}")
    private String selectedNodeName; 

    public String getSelectedNodeName() {
    return selectedNodeName;
    }

    public void setSelectedNodeName(String selectedNodeName) {
    this.selectedNodeName= selectedNodeName;
    }
```

So i tried a different approach.

```
private String selectedNodeName; 

public String getSelectedNodeName() {
    String tmp = (String)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("selectedNodeName"); 
    selectedNodeName = tmp;
    return nodename;
}

public void setSelectedNodeName(String selectedNodeName) {
    this.selectedNodeName= selectedNodeName;
}
```

This approach works only if *TreeBean* is sessionscoped and *SomeBean* is viewscoped. But i want both of the beans to be viewscoped. What should i do? Is it something wrong with my approach to composite components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set the whole bean as managed property. I had the same issues a while ago. This did solve it for me:

```
@ManagedProperty(value="#{treeBean}")
private TreeBean treeBean; 

  public String getTreeBean() {
     return treeBean;
  }

  public void setTreeBean(TreeBean treeBean) {
     this.treeBean= treeBean;
  }
```

Then you can access all the properties of TreeBean in SomeBean aswell.
Good Luck!

Comment: ty looks like i cant use bean's property as managed property.